# Add checkbox to table created CSV to HTML

Tags: javascript

I am currently building a prototype tool for my company.  I am not too familiar with javascript but I did manage to find and implement a CSV to HTML table.  The code works, and everything pulls fine, but I want to add two new variables:

1) add a checkbox in a new first column

2) if checked sum up the values in the 7th and 8th columns

This is the CSV to HTML demo: https://derekeder.github.io/csv-to-html-table/

Github: https://github.com/derekeder/csv-to-html-table

I have completed a search and found the following but I do not know if/how it can be implemented.

```
$(window).load(function(){
$("table td:first-child").prepend('<input type="checkbox" class="basic-kpi-    row"/>');
});//]]>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Ben! Please first read How to write a [MCV](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) question

Comment: Consider adding in the question that what problem you are facing and what you tried to achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add the td containing your checkbox after the row is created on your csv_to_html_table.js file, specificaly after this [line](https://github.com/derekeder/csv-to-html-table/blob/master/js/csv_to_html_table.js#L31).

It could be something like

```
row_html += '<td><input type="checkbox" class="yourClass"></td>';
```

Also you would have to add an aditional th tag on the thead row [here](https://github.com/derekeder/csv-to-html-table/blob/master/js/csv_to_html_table.js#L20)

The you could add an event listener for the inputs in order to trigger your calculations.

```
$('.yourClass').change(function(){
    if (this.checked) {
        //your code
    }
});
```